# sssd Error: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, nss, sssd, google-cloud-identity

I am trying to configure Linux machine authentication with Google secure LDAP, adding the steps below that I have done

**Added the LDAP client with below permission:**

1. Access permission: Entire Domain
2. Read user information: Entire Domain
3. Read group information: ON

**Installed SSSd in my Ubuntu box(which is running in Azure)**

`sudo apt install -y sssd sssd-tools`

**My sssd.conf file**

```
[sssd]
debug_level = 7
services = nss, pam
domains = mydomain.com

[pam]
debug_level = 7

[nss]
debug_level = 7

[domain/mydomain.com]
debug_level = 7
cache_credentials = true
ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /home/ubuntu/ssl_Linux
ldap_tls_cacert = /home/ubuntu/ssl_Linux/gldap.crt
ldap_tls_cert = /home/ubuntu/ssl_Linux/gldap.crt
ldap_tls_key = /home/ubuntu/ssl_Linux/gldap.key
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.google.com:636
ldap_search_base = ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com
ldap_group_name = uniqueMember
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_user_uuid = entryUUID
ldap_groups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true
ldap_initgroups_use_matching_rule_in_chain = true
enumerate = false
```

Here I'm able to start the SSSD service bt getting the below error

```
Nov 15 09:14:54 myserver systemd[1]: Started System Security Services Daemon.
Nov 15 09:14:55 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)
Nov 15 09:16:11 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)
Nov 15 09:16:11 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Backend is offline
Nov 15 09:17:19 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)
Nov 15 09:19:48 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)
Nov 15 09:24:02 myserver sssd[be[67530]: Could not start TLS encryption. (unknown error code)
```

**FYI:** I'm able to successfully authenticate with the google secure LDAP using below command

```
LDAPTLS_CERT=mycrt.crt LDAPTLS_KEY=mykey.key ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.google.com:636 -b "ou=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -D "my.user@mydomain.com" "(uid=my.user)" -W
```

**Refrance**: https://helpcenter.itopia.com/en/articles/2394004-configuring-google-cloud-identity-ldap-on-ubuntu-16-04-for-user-logins

Please help me on this,

Thanks :)

Comment: You may perform tcpdump on Linux box and inspect SSL/TLS handshake

Comment: Can you please more clarify or provide me some references?

Comment: I had tried the same document(Above reference document) with the new Virtual-Machine, It works fine for me

Comment: The link you provided for reference doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had tried the same [document](https://helpcenter.itopia.com/en/articles/2394004-configuring-google-cloud-identity-ldap-on-ubuntu-16-04-for-user-logins) with the new Virtual-Machine, It works fine for me.

Just need to make sure after configuring google LDAP client in http://admin.google.com/  portal **may take up to 24 hours to take effect**.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue.
adding `ldap_tls_cipher_suite = NORMAL:!VERS-TLS1.3` to sssd.conf file worked for me. I am on `Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS`